# Failed when parsing body as json - call Rasa API with request.post()

Tags: python-requests, rasa

I'm writing a function to call Rasa API for intent prediction. Here is my code:

```
def run_test():
    url = "http://localhost:5005/model/parse"
    obj = {"text": "What is your name?"}
    response = requests.post(url, data=obj)
    print(response.json())
```

I also start Rasa server with this command: **rasa run -m models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug**

And here is what I got from Rasa server terminal:
[image]

In the terminal that I excuted run_test(), I got this result:

```
{'version': '2.7.1', 'status': 'failure', 'message': 'An unexpected error occurred. Error: Failed when parsing body as json', 'reason': 'ParsingError', 'details': {}, 'help': None, 'code'
: 500}
```

Anybody help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:
Only need to use json.dumps() the object, because object in Python is different than object in json.

```
def run_test():
    url = "http://localhost:5005/model/parse"
    obj = {"text": "What is your name?"}
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(obj))
    print(response.json())
```